# Access SVG DOM / 'g' Elements Created in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to access the SVG DOM that has a variety of adobe illustrator (layered) elements within the SVG file. Ideally, I would align the HTML slider range number (1-100) with a individual 'g' elements and animate, hide, show when that range number is reached as the user engages with the slider.

Please see github project: 
https://github.com/EdBrooks/media-stroke

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  var svg = $('#svgFile').svg({loadURL: 'img/media_stroke.svg'});


  for (i=0; i < svg.length; i++) {
    var g = document.getElementsByTagName('g');
    var g1 = [{0:g}];

    console.log(g1);

    // var g1 = document.getElementById('group1').style.visibility = "hidden";

    // var re = [{0:g}];

    // console.log(re);


  }



  function InputVal() {
    this.number = 
      $('input');
        var change = input.addEventListener('change', function() {
          var value = this.value

          console.log(value);

          if (value == 23) {

            alert('wow dumb')

          }

        }, false);
  }

  InputVal();

});
```

Comment: For dealing with SVG elements in the DOM, you should always use the namespace-aware DOM methods. (In this case, `getElementsByTagNameNS`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to perform manipulation on SVG elements and do some animation.. for that you can use library like [**Snap.svg**](http://snapsvg.io/) which is similar to jQuery for HTML Dom!

Check out it's [getting started page](http://snapsvg.io/start/) (look for section 15)
or [watch video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyaiFapVOek)

Comment: Pratik! Thank you very much. I have been playing around with Snap.svg and it's exactly what I am looking for.